# Chat room activity colors not updating properly

Tags: bug, design, chat

Recently, I've noticed that the activity color-coding of rooms in the sidebar of chat hasn't been updating properly. The room will have a new message posted, it'll jump to the top, but it'll still show the inactive grayed-out or blue color.

Here's an example:

[image: TRPG General Chat showing wrong color]

Others have [also noticed this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/4?m=60584057) (mod-only link).

This is appearing in chat rev 2022.2.23.939.

Comment: So, I'm seeing kinda the opposite effect. For me, when i reload a chat tab, or when I switch rooms, all rooms in that section highlight as if there's a recent message, and the highlight resets to where it should be when I hover over them. It just started happening this morning.

Comment: What browser? OS? Try to disable userscripts, good chance one of them is responsible for this. (I [can't reproduce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKBDE.png).)

Comment: @KevinB what userscripts you have installed? Mithical, what you have? We can narrow down the list of suspects by disabling only those you both have installed.

Comment: I have SO Dark Chat Plus, it is my only chat extension. With it disabled I still had the same issue

Comment: I've been noticing this from mobile as well, @ShadowWizardHatesOmicron, and I don't have any scripts on there.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce it. @Mithical Maybe it is related to per site chat theme?

Comment: I'm now seeing the same thing mithical is, in addition to the highlighting being off on initial load. when a new message is posted that pushes a different room to the top, it doesn't gain the "active" highlight until i hover over it.